# How can we change the color of radio buttons (and labels) for AppScipt?

Tags: google-apps-script

I just wanted to ask if there is a way to set the colors of the labels and the 'buttons' in radio buttons for Google AppScript (GMail Addon). Currently, the selected option is colored green and i can't even set the selected text to be bold. This is how it looks like for now :

[image]

As for the code, there is really nothing special. Something like this :

```
var radioGroup = CardService.newSelectionInput()
  .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.RADIO_BUTTON)
  .setTitle("A group of radio buttons. Only a single selection is allowed.")
  .setFieldName("checkbox_field")
  .addItem("radio button one title", "radio_one_value", true)
  .addItem("radio button two title", "radio_two_value", false)
  .addItem("radio button three title", "radio_three_value", false);
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colour of the checkboxes is set by Google and can't be changed within the scopes of `CardService`. I would suggest filing a feature request if you would like to see this added: https://issuetracker.google.com

Comment: I suspected this too. Thank you.